# Safe conversion from __int64 to size_t

Tags: c++, c, windows, type-conversion, warnings

I am working on Windows OS with Visual Studio 2017, and I obtained the following function to determine the size of a file from one of SO's answers:

```
__int64 FileSize(const char *filename)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return -1; // error condition, could call GetLastError to find out more
    }

    LARGE_INTEGER size;
    if (!GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &size)) {
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return -1; // error condition, could call GetLastError to find out more
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return size.QuadPart;
}
```

So, am using it to determine a file size, in order to allocate memory dynamically accordingly with `malloc()`. Since the function `malloc()` accept a `size_t` type, I assigned the return value of `FileSize()` function to a size_t variable, but I got the following warning:

> main.cpp(67): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from '__int64' to '::size_t', possible loss of data

In this case, How would I safely store the size of the file within a `size_t` variable? I know I could cast the return value to `size_t` and dismiss the warning, but would it be safe/correct?

Comment: is it c or c++ ?

Comment: In the 2015 MSVC I use, `sizeof(size_t)` is 4. I guess that is why you get the message about possible loss of data.

Comment: Are you compiling for 32 bits or 64 bits?  `size_t` basically represents the range of addresses you can have.

Comment: If you compile in 32-bit mode, `size_t` will be 32 bits. A file *could* be larger than what fits in 32 bits. If you are **sure** it's not, you could try a cast. Otherwise you could perhaps use `unsigned long long` or `std::uint64_t` instead of `size_t`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm compiling for 32 bits.

Comment: Moreover, my Windows 7 system will not allow the program to use more than about 2 Gb memory anyway, as the sum of static and dynamic allocations. I don't know if that applies to Windows 10.

Comment: @machine_1 That means `size_t` is going to be a `unsigned` or `unsigned long`.  You'll never be able to fully convert a 64 bit type to a 32 bit type.  Best you can do is check the return and make sure it is not larger then what `size_t` can hold.

Comment: use LARGE_INTEGER.quadpart to save the value you get from getfilesize, If highpart is set you know things are bad otherwise use Lowpart to allocate memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very much system-specific. On some systems, `size_t` may be smaller than `int64_t`, which would give the warning. But of course you can't malloc more than what will fit inside a `size_t` anyway.

It is most likely safe to do `size_t s = (size_t)some_int64;`.

However, if you are feeling paranoid, you can add a check/assert:

```
#include <stdint.h>
...
if(some_int64 > SIZE_MAX) // this line is fully portable
{
  halt_and_catch_fire();
}
```

`SIZE_MAX` is a constant representing the maximum value that a `size_t` variable can hold.

Comment: If not a check for `some_int64 < 0` also  needed for safe conversion from `__int64` to `size_t`?  Of course negative file sizes are not expected.

Comment: @chux Of course if `GetFileSizeEx` spits out negative values, then all bets are off. But this should be checked by the caller code using the `FileSize` function, which apparently returns -1 upon error.

Answer (score 2):

The size_t type is implementation-defined.
So there is no way to be sure the value of __int64 can be safely stored in a size_t type.
I would suggest to use a static_assert:

```
static_assert(sizeof(__int64)<=sizeof(size_t), 
"Unable to safely store an __int64 value in a size_t variable");
```

This would create an error during the compile process if size_t is smaller than __int64.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t for more Information.

Comment: This will however block the possibly fine & correct program from compiling. The OP has an interface with `int64_t`, but those variables do not necessarily take greater values than what can fit inside a `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` is smaller than `__int64` when you are compiling 32-bit applications.

If you know the files you are working with are "small" (< 2 GB) you can sidestep the issue a bit by casting and just aborting if the file is somehow very large:

```
UINT64 size = FileSize(...);
if (size > ~(size_t)0) // You might want to use SIZE_MAX instead of the ~ trick if you want to stay portable
{
  printf("File is too large!\n");
}
else
{
  void*data = malloc((size_t) size);
  if (!data)
    printf("Out of memory, file is too large?\n");
  else
    ...
}
```

If on the other hand the files can be large then you cannot assume that you will be able to read the whole thing into memory at once because the machine might not have enough memory or you might run out of address space (usually around 2 GB in a 32-bit Windows process). In this case you should use [memory mapped files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx) instead with a smaller view.

Comment: On a unicorn platform `~(size_t)0` can be greater than `SIZE_MAX` (when `int/unsigned` wider than `size_t`. Perhaps `(size_t) -1`?  I am confident it is fully portable.

Comment: I already made a comment with SIZE_MAX in the code but this is Windows and it is always two's complement.

Comment: It is not a 2's complement concern.  But of rank of `size_t` vs. `int/unsigned` - something that is not defined. - sorry if that was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling for 32-bit, `size_t` will only be 32 bit.

So it is recommended that you return `size.LowPart` instead and either ignore or error out if `size.HighPart` is not zero.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to handle larger files in a 32-bit process, you just cannot read the whole file into memory at once.